# imacros use of % and $

Tags: imacros

this code works:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:formular ATTR=ID:reg CONTENT=%1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:formular ATTR=ID:code CONTENT=%67
```

this code doesn't work:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:formular ATTR=ID:reg CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:formular ATTR=ID:code CONTENT={{!COL3}}
```

Or any variation thereof

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:formular ATTR=ID:reg CONTENT=%{{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:formular ATTR=ID:code CONTENT=%{{!COL3}}
```

or

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:formular ATTR=ID:reg CONTENT=%*{{!COL2}}*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:formular ATTR=ID:code CONTENT=%*{{!COL3}}*
```

And it doesn't work even if the csv file contains %1 and %67 directly.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you try to put in csv 1 and 67 and use TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:formular ATTR=ID:reg CONTENT=%{{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:formular ATTR=ID:code CONTENT=%{{!COL3}}

Answer (score 0):

Example:

`<select>
<option value="this">Next</option>
</select>`

If you are using `%`, then iMacros will match the value **this**.
If you are using `$`, will match the value **Next**.

In your case you should use `${{!COL2}}` and `${{!COL3}}`

Comment: Thid is an old question, I've stopped trying to understand how it works :p    I work around this issue using javascript. %{{n}}, where n is a javascript variable passed to imacros through iimSet, works very well. So I load everything in javascript arrays and pass them to iim and I'm happy!

Comment: it doesn't matters if you load data from arrays or csv file, i just explained how it works % & $ :)

Comment: got that. what I mean to say is that it worked as expected (as explained on iopus wiki) when I was passing a javascript var to imacros. when i was loading data from a csv directly in an iim it simply did not work. it is very possible that the problem is fixed now and everything works well. there have been both firefox and imacros updates since i first asked the question